# Probability Theory - Combinations

Tags: probability-theory

Please, I would like some help with the following problem. I tried to use combinations but I am wondering if I have to use also the Bayes formula, in the process of solving it. The problem is at it follows:

“There is a box with 3 red balls, 5 white, and 2 blue ones. We choose one by one, eight of these balls, we write down the color of each one and we put them again back to the box. We haνe to calculate the probability, among the eight chosen balls, to have:

a) up to 2 white balls 
  b) up to 6 white balls

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Let $W$ be the number of white balls you choose. You want $\Bbb P(W\le2)=\Bbb P(W=0) + \Bbb P(W=1) + \Bbb P(W=2)$. Then work each of these out individually. When working these out, just assume there are 5 white, 5 non-white, so each selection is like a coin flip - a $50-50\%$ chance of getting white or not.

Comment: Since the balls are replaced you are dealing with $8$ independent experiments that have equal probability to succeed. A success can be identified with drawing a white ball. So you must apply [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Answer (score 1):

Well that is just a tricky question.
Being $R+B=5$, when extracting $8$ balls you must have **at least** $3$ white : so a) $0$  b) $1$